# Pass output from one pipeline run and use as parameter in another pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

The way my ADF setup currently works, is that I have multiple pipelines, each containing atleast one activity. Then I have one big pipeline that sort of chains these pipelines together.

However, now in the big "master" pipeline, I would like to use the output of an activity from one pipeline and then pass it to another pipeline. All of this orchestrated from the "master" pipeline.

My "master" pipeline would look something like this:

[image]

What I have tried to do is adding a parameter to "Execute Pipeline2", and I have tried passing:

```
@activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipeline.runId.output.runOutput
@activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineRunId.output.runOutput
@activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.runOutput
```

How would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unfortunately we don't have a way to pass the output of an activity across pipelines. Right now pipelines don't have outputs (only activities).
We have a workitem that will allow a user to choose what should be the output for a pipeline (imagine a pipeline with 40 activities, user would be able to choose the output of activity 3 as pipeline output). However, this workitem is in very early stages so don't expect to see this soon.

For now, the only way would be to save the output that you want in storage (blob, for example) and then read it and pass it to the other pipeline. Another method could be a web activity that gets the pipeline run (passing run id) and you get the output using ADF SDK or REST API, and then you pass that to the next Execute Pipeline activity.